# Bootstrap Carousel Next Prev Link Doesnt Work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am using Bootstrap Carousel Element in my design and since i wanted to use the fade in Effect i extended plugin as suggested by in this [link](http://www.bootply.com/64693)

Now the Next and Prev Buttons wont work.

Link: http://play.mink7.com/suoll/v2

```
<div data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" id="carousel-example-captions carousel_fade">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item"> <img alt="900x500" src="images/slider/img1.jpg">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>First slide label</h3>
              <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item active"> <img alt="900x500" src="images/slider/img2.jpg">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Second slide label</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item"> <img alt="900x500" src="images/slider/img3.jpg">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Third slide label</h3>
              <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#carousel-example-captions " class="left carousel-control"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> </a> 
        <a data-slide="next" href="#carousel-example-captions" class="right carousel-control"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> </a> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watching your code I think that the error is here (wrong id assignment)

```
 id="carousel-example-captions carousel_fade"
```

should be

```
 id="carousel-example-captions" class="carousel_fade"
```

then (also remove space at the end of prev href property)

```
<a data-slide="prev" href="#carousel-example-captions" class="left carousel-control"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> </a> 
<a data-slide="next" href="#carousel-example-captions" class="right carousel-control"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> </a> </div>
```

in this way the id in href of prev and next should work